# How can I do fog that is denser at the bottom?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, world

[image: The round ball is a point ligt]I'm trying to add a fog to a sea scene that wouldn't cover the sky and get denser further down, so I could not see the horizon.

[image: The World node]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28648/how-to-make-a-z-depth-and-height-pass and  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43600/low-lying-fog-bounding-object-rendering-as-solid/43648#43648

Comment: Also **you can't use volume and surface at the same time in the world settings**. See this answers: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49893/rendering-environment-pass-without-combined-pass-in-cycles/49923#49923 http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19227/1853 related: https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/materials/volume.html?highlight=volume%20world#volume-world

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33340/blending-floor-and-background-to-appear-as-one and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53589/how-would-i-fade-out-the-edges-of-a-plane-in-cycles

Comment: To hide the horizon you need aerial respective, which is fog that gets thicker as it recedes into distance. You could also add a plane with ramp texture that gets thicker at the bottom. Then place plane infront of horizon.

Answer (score 1):

This is a cheat as well as  faster render. Place a textured plane in front of the horizon with transparent at the top and sky horizon color at the bottom. Use a linear gradient to alter the Fac value of the Mix Shader.

[image: fake aerial perspective plane]
[image: material for the plane]

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution here is to use a volumetric shader of your choice in a smoke generator with dissolve on and slow, then use multiply on the density input into that shader to change how much fog you will get. I quick whipped together an example which isn't of very good quality (using CPU compute on an old CPU to render volumetric effects is super slow) but should get the point across. You can totally change the final look and feel as well by altering the volumetric shader and using something more complex that what I used.

[image: Poor example of fog]

[image: Settings for the fog]

Change exactly how long the "Time" setting is depending on where exactly you put the flow of the fog. In my case I put it below the ocean model, so I set it to 2. Keep in mind though that the shorter the number you put in the time, the smaller the gradation will be between the lowest and highest parts of the fog.

And finally if you've never done much for the smoke simulator before, just remember to use Alt+A to simulate so that your smoke will actually start to rise, and make sure your timeline has an end time around 50 frames out at least to ensure there is enough time for the smoke to react properly.

Comment: It is a grate work arund and will probebly worke fine for moste of the time but it will depend on the smoke simulator.